# Print all array(looping) from ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the code so i get that result :

```
$.ajax({
                    url: location.origin+'/getcat?t='+id,
                    dataType:"json"
}).success(function(data){
                    var array = data.data;
                    array.ForEach(function(print){
                        console.log(print.title);
});
```

I have an ajax callback like this:

[image]

and this is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: array.ForEach is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (blogs:811)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)
```

I've try using `data.ForEach(function(){});` to print out all the `data` but error. I know this should can be done with php `foreach()` but i need to do it in javascript. How to do it ?

Comment: please provide code so i can debug what is the issue

Comment: come with your code

Comment: You might want to read and post the error message

Comment: Please, read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: ok i'll will add some code

Comment: And the error message tells you that `ForEach` is no method of this object !? case! JS is case sensitive.

Comment: ok thats the problem thank @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Just three tips to improve your development skills:

First, you said you had an error. Just read the error and you will know the problem (Most times errors are verbose enough for that). Second, if you don't have a clue then you should share here the error, so they have additional data that can help discover the problem. And third, it seems that you have indentation problems, which may lead to difficult readable code.

The problem here is that `ForEach` must be with the first letter lowercase, as JavaScript uses Lower Camel Case, so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: location.origin+'/getcat?t='+id,
    dataType:"json"
}).success(function(data){
    var array = data.data;
    array.forEach(function(print){ // camelCase it
        console.log(print.title);
    }); // You forgot to add this close block. I guess you have it elsewhere in your code.
});
```